# Why can't I see my bitbucket commits?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am working on a repo on bitbucket. I cloned my project on an other laptop (I have 2 ssh keys on my account) and since I have added the second ssh key, I can't see my commits from the first laptop .

when I do

```
git push feature feature/353
```

I get the following error:

> fatal: 'feature' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

```
git push <repository> <refspec>
```

Unless you have renamed your remote repository to `feature`, it is likely called `origin`. Check `git remote` for the remote repository names. You probably wanted to push `feature` as `feature/353`. You need to use a colon for that:

```
git push origin feature:feature/353
```

For more information, check `git push --help` or `man git-push`.